# How to update firefox in ububtu

Tags: firefox, ubuntu

My Ubuntu software center crashes whenever i tried to open it. I came to understand it is after the python installation.

Now i want to update my Firefox browser.

How the Firefox browser is upgraded using the command line in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run 2 commands to upgrade specific package:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade firefox
```